# Same question, but I need a different answer. What do i do?

Tags: discussion

Someone else has already asked the same question I have, back in 2011. The accepted answer does not solve my problem. The post in question is : [How do I deal with my baby pulling herself up in her crib?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2946/how-do-i-deal-with-my-baby-pulling-herself-up-in-her-crib)

For various reasons, the accepted answer wouldn't work for me. Should I leave a comment there and ask for more help? Should I ask a new question with mention of how this existing solution doesn't work for me? Is it possible to "bump" questions to bring it to users notice again now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate thing to do in this circumstance is to ask a new question. Explain in that question why the other question and answer don’t work for you. Everyone’s circumstances are different; just explain yours, and acknowledge the other question - that way it’s not closed as duplicate.

Comment: This is often why I hesitate to close a potential duplicate. The situation often has to be exactly 100% for me to consider dupe closing. Parenting isn't programming. All situations are different.

Answer (score 2):

While @Joe's answer may end up being the way forwards, in general I'd recommend a step before that - offer a bounty on the existing question, and in the reason section just select "Needs More Attention"

You can then even leave a comment on that question to say that you tried the ideas offered by existing answers and they didn't work so you were looking for more info.

If that doesn't give you anything, or if you are a relatively new user with not enough rep for a bounty, then I agree - ask a new question and refer to the existing one.

Comment: Great idea. My only concern is that this works well for those users with enough rep to offer a substantial bounty. What about those users who are new or low rep needing help?

Comment: Good point @SomeShinyObject - edited to include